# How can we save the data from a complex object in Firebase Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use complex objects to manage data in my app. For example I have an object defined by the "Defi class" (meaning Challenge in French).

Here is the Defi class :

```
class Defi {
  final int modeApprentissage;
  final DateTime date;
  final double score;
  final int seconds;
  final List mots;
  final List erreurs;
  final List listes;
  final int langue;
  final int type;
  final int typeMots1;
  final int typeMots2;
  const Defi(
      {required this.modeApprentissage,
      required this.date,
      required this.type,
      required this.langue,
      required this.typeMots1,
      required this.typeMots2,
      required this.score,
      required this.seconds,
      required this.listes,
      required this.mots,
      required this.erreurs});
}
```

I have a LIST of Defi that I would like to save on FIREBASE FIRESTORE.
My question : Is it absolutely necessary to transform my list of Defi into a map to save it on Firestore ? Or is there another way ?

Here is how I do it :

```
 List _defisMap = [];
    for (Defi def in _defis) {
      _defisMap.add({
        'modeApprentissage': def.modeApprentissage,
        'type': def.type,
        'langue': def.langue,
        'typeMots1': def.typeMots1,
        'typeMots2': def.typeMots2,
        'date': def.date,
        'score': def.score,
        'seconds': def.seconds,
        'listes': def.listes,
        'mots': def.mots,
        'erreurs': def.erreurs,
      });
    }
    if (await _connectivity.checkConnectivity() != ConnectivityResult.none) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('familyAccounts')
          .doc(_accountEmail)
          .update({
        'defis': _defisMap,
      });
```

I read in some article that in classes such as Defi, I could add a "factory" constructor ? Does this have anything to do with what I'd like to do ?

I created another class :

```
class Classes {
  final String code;
  final String nom;

  const Classes({
    required this.code,
    required this.nom,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'code': code,
        'nom': nom,
      };


  factory Classes.fromMap(Map data) => Classes(
        code: data['code'] ?? '',
        nom: data['nom'] ?? '',
      );
}
```

I save a list of Classes on Firestore. No problem.
But to retrieve this list : I must go from the list of maps that is on Firestore to a list of "Classes". And I just can't get the syntax right !

Here is my code :

```
final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> docInfo =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('familyAccounts')
            .doc(_accountEmail)
            .get();

    _typeCompte =
        docInfo['typeCompte'] == 'prof' ? TypeCompte.prof : TypeCompte.eleve;
    _userId = docInfo['userId'];
    _linked = docInfo['linked'];
    _name = docInfo['name'];
    _avatar = docInfo['avatar'];
    _classe = docInfo['classe'];
    _classeCode = docInfo['classeCode'];
    _country = docInfo['country'];
    _region = docInfo['region'];
    docInfo['langue'] == 'french'
        ? _selectedIoLanguage = Language.french
        : _selectedIoLanguage = Language.english;
    _teacherCode = docInfo['teacherCode'];
    _indexList = docInfo['indexList'];
    _nbrList = docInfo['nbrList'];
    _dateCreationCompte = docInfo['dateCreation'].toDate();
    _defiTemp = docInfo['defis'].toList();

    if (_typeCompte == TypeCompte.prof) {
      _etablissement = docInfo['etablissement'];
      _mesClasses = docInfo['mesClasses'];
```

(_mesClasses should be a list of "Classes").

I sense it should be some kind of xxx.map() etc.... but I don't master this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create toJson method to set as a map of your list. If you have a list of Defi class. You can send it to map.

```
class Defi {
  final int modeApprentissage;
  final DateTime date;
  final double score;
  final int seconds;
  final List mots;
  final List erreurs;
  final List listes;
  final int langue;
  final int type;
  final int typeMots1;
  final int typeMots2;
  const Defi(
      {required this.modeApprentissage,
      required this.date,
      required this.type,
      required this.langue,
      required this.typeMots1,
      required this.typeMots2,
      required this.score,
      required this.seconds,
      required this.listes,
      required this.mots,
      required this.erreurs});

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
       'modeApprentissage': modeApprentissage,
        'type': type,
        'langue': langue,
        'typeMots1': typeMots1,
        'typeMots2': typeMots2,
        'date': date,
        'score': score,
        'seconds': seconds,
        'listes': listes,
        'mots': mots,
        'erreurs': erreurs,
      };
}
```

Your list name is should be `List<Defi> _defis` then map it with toJson. `var jsonMap = _defisMap.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();`

```
var jsonMap = _defis.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();

if (await _connectivity.checkConnectivity() != ConnectivityResult.none) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('familyAccounts')
          .doc(_accountEmail)
          .update({
        'defis': jsonMap,
      });
```

You can also Map it from api call with fromJson method. Here is the way. Add this to your Defi class.

```
factory Defi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Defi(
        modeApprentissage: json['modeApprentissage'],
        type: json['type'],
        langue: json['langue'],
        typeMots1: json['typeMots1'],
        typeMots2: json['typeMots2'],
        date: json['date'],
        score: json['score'],
        seconds: json['seconds'],
        listes: json['listes'],
        mots: json['mots'],
        erreurs: json['erreurs'],);
  }
```

And when you call api you need to call that function.

```
final Map<String, dynamic> jsonResult = json.decode(response.body);


//if it is a list returning from api. You can change variables what you got from api.


(jsonResult as List<dynamic>)
          .map((data) => Defi.fromJson(data))
          .toList();

// if it is not list 

Defi.fromJson(jsonResult);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I added the JSON Method as you suggested and everything works. It's cleaner code. Could I do something similar when I retrieve the data ... mapping it back to the "complex object" ?

Comment: Yes, there is a method. I will edit my answer and show it to you.

Comment: Hi again :) I edited my question - I added a question at the end. It's similar to what you sent, but am trying it a little differently, but I can't get the syntax right... Can you have a look ?

Comment: I don't understand your line "json.decode(response.body);" What is "response?body" thing ?

Comment: It is your docInfo which means jsonResult is docInfo for your api call. Do not use it. It is not for your api call. It is my bad. You should use like Defi.fromJson(docInfo);

Comment: It worked !! I used the .fromMap instead of fromJson. Thanks for your help ! Have you had a look at the other answer that was given to my question ? (below) It seems interesting too. But can't really understand the syntax to implement it...

Comment: Actually, I generally use JsonSerializable and it works with my additional API. I did not work on Firebase Firestore. That is why I am not familiar with that answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243053/discussion-between-sylvainjack-and-burakaybi).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely necessary to transform into a map. Firestore is a document store, the definition of a document is a json object, which is represented by a map in Dart. BUT, you don't have to do it "manually". Most of us use packages to do the mapping for us.

[Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) or [JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and then we simply call `.toJson` and pass that to the function. In addition to that Firestore now supports the `.withConverter` function so you don't have to do any conversion if you know what type the collection is storing.

So if you know the type of a collection is Defi you can do

```
   final defyCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('defis').withConverter<Defi>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
          final data = snapshot.data()!;
          data['id'] = snapshot.id;
          return Defi.fromJson(data);
        },
        toFirestore: (object, _) => object.toJson(),
      )
```

This way you can simply use the `defyCollection` and the data property or function will be typed to your type.

Comment: Would this also work with a document ? "defi" is not a collection but a field in a document.

Comment: If your field is a map matching this then yes, you can just call fromJson, it'll serialize all nested objects as well.

Comment: I'm going to try, I'm afraid I'm gonna have trouble with the syntax ;)

Comment: Are you there ? I edited my question (at the end). Here is my problem. I have a collection of "users". For each user : I have a document which contains many different types of elements : strings, bools, list of maps (coming from my complex objects) etc.... As shown in the code (the edited part of my question), I download all this information by "getting" the document and then filling variables etc... For the complex objects I use loops and fill lists etc... How can I use your technique to do that knowing my document contains many different types of data ?

Comment: Hello :) Are you online ?

Comment: @SylvainJack you would do it exactly the same way as metioned in my answer. That's what I meant by saying you don't have to do it manually. You define your class with your properties, you know the data's type and property name. You create those, generate the model then call .fromJson on it and it'll serialise. In addition you can use the converter to have it automatically happen when you get your data. As shown in the answer above.